# jQuery remove div when I change the select box

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is:

if I the the item 1 and item 2 are checked or selected  the divs above needs to be removed after the user select the dropdown bellow. (need remove both, does not matter if the user selected: theremove div above 1 or remove div above 2)

here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9jbatfv/4/

I hope I was very clear in my question

the max I did was this here, I could not continue. :(

```js
//click
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  var id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
  $('.show-content #' + id).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }

  $("span").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
    selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
//click

//grid
var $select = $('.js-my-select'),
  $images = $('.js-my-image');

$select.on('change', function() {
  var value = '.' + $(this).val();
  $images.show().not(value).hide();
});
//end search
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="bills">item 1</label>
      <span for="bills" class="pull-right">()</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="bills">item 2</label>
      <span for="bills" class="pull-right">()</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="show-content">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;  height: 50px; display:none;" id="item1"> Grid item 1</div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;  height: 50px; display:none;" id="item2"> Grid item 2</div>
</div>

<h1>explanation:</h1>
<p>
if I the the item 1 and item 2 are checked or selected  the divs above needs to be removed after the user select the dropdown bellow. (need remove both, does not matter if the user selected: theremove div above 1 or remove div above 2)
</p>

<select id="selectbasic" name="my-select" class="js-my-select form-control">
  <option value="nothing" selected>Select</option>
  <option value="grid">remove div above 1.</option>
  <option value="expanded">reomve div above 2</option>
</select>

<!--  expanded style for select -->

<div class="js-my-image grid" style="display: none;">
  divs above were removed and here is the message 1
</div>

<div class="js-my-image expanded" style="display: none;">
 div above were removed and here is the message 2
</div>
```

Comment: and whats your problem/question?

Comment: what I am trying to do is:

if I the the item 1 and item 2 are checked or selected the divs above needs to be removed after the user select the dropdown bellow. (need remove both, does not matter if the user selected: theremove div above 1 or remove div above 2)

Comment: yes, I get what you want to do. but what is your problem/question/error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/b9jbatfv/8/

```js
//click
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  var id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
  $('.show-content #' + id).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }

  $("span").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
    selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
//click

//grid
var $select = $('.js-my-select'),
  $images = $('.js-my-image');

$select.on('change', function() {
  var value = '.' + $(this).val();
  $images.show().not(value).hide();
  var checkedAll = true;
  $('.bill-type li').each(function(){
       if(!$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
   checkedAll = false;
  });
  if(checkedAll)
       $('.bill-type').slideUp();
});
//end search
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="bills">item 1</label>
      <span for="bills" class="pull-right">()</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="bills">item 2</label>
      <span for="bills" class="pull-right">()</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="show-content">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;  height: 50px; display:none;" id="item1"> Grid item 1</div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;  height: 50px; display:none;" id="item2"> Grid item 2</div>
</div>

<h1>explanation:</h1>
<p>
if I the the item 1 and item 2 are checked or selected  the divs above needs to be removed after the user select the dropdown bellow. (need remove both, does not matter if the user selected: theremove div above 1 or remove div above 2)
</p>

<select id="selectbasic" name="my-select" class="js-my-select form-control">
  <option value="nothing" selected>Select</option>
  <option value="grid">remove div above 1.</option>
  <option value="expanded">reomve div above 2</option>
</select>

<!--  expanded style for select -->

<div class="js-my-image grid" style="display: none;">
  divs above were removed and here is the message 1
</div>

<div class="js-my-image expanded" style="display: none;">
 div above were removed and here is the message 2
</div>
```

Added `jQuery .slideUp` method to hide the `ul` and slideUp will happen only when ywo checkboxes are selected.

`$('.bill-type').slideUp();`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add that to your function that activates on change:

```
$("#item1").css("display", "none");
$("#item2").css("display", "none");
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9jbatfv/5/